# Context.Request.Form - Get Unchecked Checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, forms, checkbox, unchecked

Is there any way to get all checkboxes using context.request ?

It has only checked checkboxes its keys collection. I need the "unchecked" checkboxes also.

I cannot rely on checkbox name. It can have any name, and I am handling it in a handler. Otherwise, if `context.Request.Form.Get("checkbox1")` returns **Nothing** then it is **unchecked**.

But, name of the checkbox is not pre-defined.

Any solution ?

Sample Code:

HTML Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1"> One<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2"> Two<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3"> Three<br>
```

On submit, it will call the handler where I need to process. I do not design this HTML pages, but the code will be like this.

Handler Code:

```
For Each s As String In context.Request.Form
   ControlValue = IIf(context.Request.Form(s) IsNot Nothing, context.Request.Form(s), "")
Next
```

Here, unchecked checkboxes will not be present in context.Request.Form.

Comment: can I have some code that what you have tried?

Comment: Bhavesh - Here is a sample code.

Comment: also need code for the aspx page